# Best practice of updating an Android App?

Tags: java, android

I am building an Android App and am pretty new to this. To distribute my app it is necessary to upload it to Google Play, so that people can find and download it.

Now, when I continue the development of the app, what would be the best practice of updating the app? Is it better to upload the new version to Google Play or is it better to handle the updating process within the app's logic?

**EDIT:**

To sum all the answers up:

- Yes, upload the newest Android App (APK) to Google Play.
- Update the information on the App in Google Play according to the new version.
- Read Google's [Update your apps page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en) for more details.

Thanks to all for the helpful answers! :)

Comment: yes, you should upload it to google play. also, you can check newer version inside of your application and force to user to update it

Comment: Google is your friend :) https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

Comment: Why the hell did you downgrade -7? This question is totally legimate for someone who does his first steps in this topic. Anyway, thanks for the quick answer Adem and Nanis.

Comment: because some people seem to have nothing better to do than downvote others who are new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update the application APK from Google play itself. But if you have files  other than apk, you could update it from your server throu your appliction code.

You can intimate/notify your users about the availability and priority of the updates throu the application by cross-checking the latest version code from your server. Like -

1. check the latest version code from your server on app start (Take care to do it in an AsyncTask)
2. if latest version code is higher that the current version code of the apk, then notify the user.
3. If user wants to update, open your app page in playstore using intent.
4. If it is a critical update you can notify that the user MUST update the application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should update the app through the Google Play Store.

Let's say that you upload only verison 1.0 to the play store, and then over time, you do updates, and more updates, and more updates, until you're up to version 1.7.9.

A new Android user sees your spiffy app on the play store, but notices that your app is only 1.0, and you haven't made mention of any updates on the play store in a year.  Will that new user download the app?  Maybe, but maybe not.  People tend to want the newest and latest.

Another example, someone else runs across your app for the first time and decides to download it.  Of course, you only have 1.0 on the store.  After they run it for the first time, they discover that they have to update it already!  (Sounds a little like Windows, doesn't it?)  Some users might sit and wait for the update, but I'd be willing to bet that many would just uninstall and say forget it.  Especially if your updating server is running slowly or offline for some reason.